# Scala Breeze does not find my file on a webserver, while Java does

Tags: scala, scalatra, scala-breeze

I'm new to Scala, so there's probably something obvious I'm missing.

I've got a Scalatra webserver running, with a csv-file in the same folder as the Scalatra servlet. The webserver recognizes the file just find, and the following action:

```
get("/dependencies") {
val variable = params.get("variable")
new java.io.File("/path/to/files/my_csv_file.csv")
}
```

Works as intended and returns the csv-file as a http get request.

However, I want to use the Breeze-library to do some general operations on the csv data. When I try to load the csv file to Breezes csv reader:

```
val matrix=csvread(new file("/path/to/files/my_csv_file.csv"), ',')
```

The following error is returned by the server:

```
[error] /path/to/files/MyScalatraServlet.scala:23: not found: type file
[error]   val matrix=csvread(new file("/path/to/files/"), ',')                         
[error]                           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 18.5.2017 18:32:23
```

Although not obvious from the code, Breezes linalg module, containing the csv module, has been imported in the beginning of the file.

```
import breeze.linalg._
```

Does anyone have ideas on why this error is happening? How come Breeze does not find the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

That is a compilation error. I think following code would work:

```
val matrix = csvread(new java.io.File("/path/to/files/"), ',')
```

or

```
val matrix = csvread("/path/to/files/", ',')
```